# How to extract SVGPolyline's points as a 2D Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

My problem is that my script doesn't output the array data the way I would like it to.

As you can see here: https://pastebin.com/raw/3AcEs1gc
This shows how it currently outputs (in Google's Console.) and how I would like it to output.

My code is shown at the very bottom. I simply need it to add "[" to the very start of the array, and at the end of it add "]"
I also need it to add those after each paired number and replace the spaces after each paired number with a comma.
So it will output as a example like this `[[200,100],[250,123]]`.
& not like this `200, 400 245, 500` < Which is how it currently logs in google's console.

The pastebin link explains a bit more. If you need more detail reply. I will try my best to explain.

MY CODE:

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
// Tell the request where the file is.
xhr.open("GET", "http://someurl.com/blahblah.svg");
// Add event handler to process the file once it's been fetched.
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
// Once the text is available, create an XML parser
// and parse the text as an SVG image.
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
this.responseText.trim(),
"image/svg+xml"
);
// xmlDoc.getElements() returns something Array-like, but not an Array.
// This turns it into an Array.
const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));


var Lines = (polylines.map(
pl => [
  // Parses each 'points' attribute into an array of pairs of numbers
  pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(
    pair => pair.split(',').map(x=>+x)
  ),
  // Various stroke information

  // Convert rgb(R,G,B) to #RRGGBB
  // Leading hash, then pull out the digits with a regex
  '#' + pl.style.stroke.match(/rgb\((\d*), (\d*), (\d*)\)/)
    // Throw away everything but the digits
    .slice(1,4)
    // Convert to a number, render in hex, uppercase, pad with 0s
    .map(x=>(+x).toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2,'0'))
    // Concatenate the hex digits
    .join(''),
  +pl.style.strokeWidth,

    ]
));
console.log(Lines)  // Logs the arrays to console.
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: `pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').reduce (
    (rzArry, pair) => {
        rzArry.push (pair.split(',').map(x => parseInt(x, 10) ) );
        return rzArry;
    }
    , []
),`

Comment: Just adding `[` or `]` does not make the String an Array unless you parse it. Looks like you will want to split on `" "` and then iterate that the split each item by `","`.

Comment: Also where is your first Example Array coming from, the AJAX?

Comment: What is the input format ?

Comment: @BrockAdams This would badly fail if the attribute contains multiple spaces, tabs, or new line as separator

Answer (score 1):

Use the SVGPointList interface available from your SVGPolylineElement to extract all the [SVGPoints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint) it contains. 
Then you just have to map all these SVGPoints `x` and `y` properties to an equivalent `[x, y]` Array:

```js
makeSVGPointListIterable();

const polyline = document.querySelector('polyline');
console.log(parsePoints(polyline));

function parsePoints(elem) {
  return [...elem.points] // convert to an Array so we can map its content
    .map((pt) => [pt.x, pt.y]); // convert to an Array
}






// small monkey patch for Safari
function makeSVGPointListIterable() {
  const proto = SVGPointList.prototype;
  if (typeof proto[Symbol.iterator] !== 'function') {
    proto[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
      let current = 0;
      return {
        next: () => {
          const is_done = current === this.numberOfItems;
          return {
            done: is_done,
            value: is_done || this.getItem(current++)
          }
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- even with stoopid new lines in the attribute -->
  <polyline points="100,100 150,25 150,75
    200,0" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([new Number(3), new String('false'), new Boolean(false)]));
```

will output the following:

"[3,"false",false]"

Comment: I need it to output the array each array something like this.

Comment: ``[[100,200],[420,123],[234,351]]`` Notice the end has ``]`` and so does the start of the array, but with ``[``

Comment: That is a string, u can replace the first and last character with '[' to serve your purpose.